# ByteBuffer and partial write

Tags: java, nio

If the `ByteBuffer` is written partially, the `position` is updated and the next `_channel.write` call will resume from last position, yep?

`compact()` is not necessary?

```
private AsynchronousSocketChannel _channel;
private ByteBuffer _buffer;

final CompletionHandler<Integer, LogstashClientStream> _writeCompletionHandler = new CompletionHandler<Integer, LogstashClientStream>(){
    @Override
    public void completed(Integer sent, LogstashClientStream self) {
        if( _buffer.remaining() == 0 ){
            _buffer.clear();
            //...
        }                       
        else {
            // partial write
            self.send();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable exc, LogstashClientStream self) {
        //...
    }
};

private void send(){
    try{
        _channel.write( _buffer, this, _writeCompletionHandler);
    } catch(Throwable e){
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does the code work or not? If not, then what's not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will resume, and no, `compact()` is not necessary here. It's useful mainly in cases when you want to fill the rest of the buffer from some input stream before invoking `write()` again.